# How to create Copy constructor in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a copy constructor for the `Shape` class, so that it prints the address of the name of `s2`.

Here is my code:

```
class Shape {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    string * name;

public:
    //constructor
    Shape() {
        cout << "Inside the constructor" << endl;

    }

    //Copy constructor
    Shape(Shape& source) {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;

        name = new string[name];

        copy(source.name, source.name, this->getName);
    }


    //Destructor
    ~Shape() {}

    void setX(int px) {
        x = px;
    }
    void setY(int py) {
        y = py;
    }

    void setName(string * str) {
        name = str;
    }
    string * getName() {
        return name;
    }


int main()
{
    Shape s1;
    s1.setName( new string("first shape") );

    Shape s2(s1);
    cout << s1.getName() << endl; //will display the address of name for s1
    cout << s2.getName() << endl; //will display the address of name for s2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name = new string[name];` what is this supposed to do? You don't need a heap allocated srring here at all, use `string name;`. You won't need a copy constructor or destructor either.

Answer (score 0):

As you created the string pointer member `name` for `s1` and you're just copying it to `s2` when invoking the copy constructor, it's just the expected behaviour that it displays the same address as for `s1` - it simply copies the pointer.

If you want a unique name per shape, just create a static method / free function that creates a new name, and call that one in both, constructor and copy constructor, to give each new instance a unique name.

For what it's worth, using the `new` operator here is not really common (are you coming from a Java background?) - you may just want to use a regular `std::string`, in which case you don't have to do the memory management yourself (your code basically has a memory leak right now, because you don't call `delete` anywhere to free the memory allocated via `new`).

P.S.: Just saw you just edited and changed your code, while I was typing my answer... I won't keep track of the changes (please excuse that), but I leave my answer here for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following code?

```
 //Copy constructor
    Shape(Shape& source) {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
        name = new string[name];
        *name = *source.name;
    }
```